# How to get a second Bachelor's degree in an unrelated field?

Tags: university, undergraduate

I was studying journalism in my country, but I realised it's not for me at all. I kind of had to apply there because there aren't really any good schools in things I was interested in. I was thinking of applying to a Physics school in the USA or UK, but all the universities I looked up say I won't be eligible because I already hold a Bachelor's degree, so what do I do? Has anyone of you done that before? Which schools allow this, since top schools won't?

1. And please, don't suggest I go and get a master's in journalism instead, that is not happening.
2. And yes, I can do physics and am really good at maths so none of that *"are you sure you want it, physics is hard..."*
3. No, money is not an issue for me if I won't be eligible for any type of scholarship.

Comment: I hope not your spelling was the real reason of the rejections.

Comment: duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/69249/second-bachelors-degree?rq=1

Comment: To whoever made the edit that changed "realised" to "realized" with a snarky comment about spelling: I have approved the other parts of that edit, but reversed that change, as "realised" is a perfectly valid UK spelling.

Comment: Why are trolls allowed to edit other people's questions?

Comment: I was really pleased to note that this implies Oxford isn't a top university, but it appears Cambridge isn't either. I'd suggest "second undergraduate degree" as a UK search term. https://www.ox.ac.uk/admissions/undergraduate/applying-to-oxford/second-undergraduate-degree?wssl=1 https://www.undergraduate.study.cam.ac.uk/why-cambridge/support/mature-students/second-undergraduate-degrees

Comment: Seriously? I think both of these are top schools in my opinion and I'd be overcome with happiness if I get a chance to study in either of them, though I'd prefer studying in the US solely because I have a couple of friends there... also, apparently oxford allows second bachelor's, which is frankly an amazing news

Answer (score 1):

There are many schools that do not have odd requirements that they only teach those whose virtue has not been smeared by another degree.

Apply to programs that accept candidates regardless of what degrees they currently posses.

Comment: I did find some, but are they really all that good? I wanted to go to one of the top schools but all of them seem to not want to allow people like me to attend. I know you don't have to go to Harvard or MIT only just to be successful in life but still... I'll look into others, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised to hear schools are telling you your previous degree is an impediment. I currently have a Bachelors of Arts in political science and am entering my third year of electrical engineering at a different university (both in Canada). I never encountered any issues when applying for my second degree as a result of having completed by first. While I can't speak for schools in the US or UK, I feel that you could easily apply to Canadian universities to study physics (or engineering :)).

Comment: Good idea. A question though - did you by any chance not mention the fact that you have a Bachelor's degree?

Comment: @Sam it is not a good idea to try and hide your first degree when applying for a second. If you are accepted on the basis that you don't have a degree and then the university later finds out you do... well, things might not work out too well.

Comment: That's exactly why I asked them that

Comment: @Sam - I think what astronat meant was that it would have been foolish to hide the first degree, and therefore it seems likely that ngereluk would have disclosed it.

Comment: @sam Yes, the school I currently attend is aware I already have a degree. They didn't really seem to care tbh.... Most uni admins just comment that my situation is unique. Also I got credit for all my humanities course so that was nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to cover the tuition yourself, perhaps you could take the courses you're interested in as a non-degree-seeking (non-matriculated) student.

With this method, you would not "apply for admission."

But I'm not sure how this would affect your immigration status.

Comment: I want a degree actually. If I didn't I wouldn't even be asking this question. I want to work as a Physicist